# I can't connect to MySQL with Airflow connections

Tags: mysql, airflow

I want to connect to MySQL with Airflow Connection, but I can’t.
Is there any missing information from the attached image?
I have already set up Airflow's VPC to connect to a remote database.

Also, when you press the Test button, a red frame like an error window is displayed at the top of the screen, but no wording is written.
This phenomenon occurs when something is entered in "Host".
If the input of "Host" is empty, the error `(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")` is output.
Is this a bug?

Each version is below.
Composer
　1.18.1
Airflow
　2.2.3
MySQL to connect to
　10.2.25-MariaDB-log

[image]

Comment: You must provide a host. If you test the connection using a hook within a python script, what error do you get?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

MySQL Hook has airflow.hooks.mysql_hook and airflow.providers.mysql.hooks.mysql. Which should I use for connection test?

Also, I'm developing with GCP Composer in an Airflow web server environment. Can you tell me how to test the connection?